# How to change the host address that my web server listens on?

Tags: networking, ip, hosts

I am setting up a web server on my Ubuntu host. To be specifically, it is `gdbgui`. According to its help info, I can use `--host` to specify the host IP it listens on. And on my host, I have below IP configuraton:

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:9f:02:c9:97  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp89s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1c:69:7a:a5:c2:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x6a200000-6a2fffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 163716  bytes 56247108 (56.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 163716  bytes 56247108 (56.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet **192.168.50.69**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.50.255 <========= HERE
        inet6 fe80::3fd:752e:5ded:467f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 70:9c:d1:21:c5:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 270277  bytes 117510355 (117.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 15  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93011  bytes 45155962 (45.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I want to use the 192.168.50.69 so my other machines in the same LAN can access it.

But it always listens on 127.0.0.1. Even I explicitly specify the `--host` option for `gdbgui`.

```
gdbgui --host 192.168.50.69 ...
```

How can I change it? I guess this question is not specific to gdbgui.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved for gdbgui.

I need to specify the host name rather than the host IP for the `--host` option. Like below:

```
gdbgui --host myBox ...
```

Then I need to modify the `/etc/hosts` file to specify the IP address for the host name. Like below:

```
192.168.50.69   myBox
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it, but it's strange that the program will accept a name (found in /etc/hosts) but not an IP address directly!